# Extracting files from Oracle blob fields;

Tags: java, database, oracle, blob

I am trying to extract a file from a blob using the values found in the fields following the blob column. My solution works, but it is rather slow.

I extracted 169MB(727 different files) in about 1 hour. That's about 12 files a minute.
most of the  files are usually between 5KB and 50KB but can sometimes be as big as 2MB. I am working with a local Oracle database.

Is there anything I could do to make my code more efficient? If not, what other factors might affect the speed of the process? Here is the method's code:

```
public void beginExtraction(String FileOutDir, String blobSQL,
        String fileSuffix, Connection conn) {

    if ((FileOutDir != null) && (blobSQL != null) && (conn != null)) {
        PreparedStatement selBlobs = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        if (conn != null) {
            if (blobSQL != null) {
                try {

                    selBlobs = conn.prepareStatement(blobSQL);
                    ResultSet rs = selBlobs.executeQuery();
                    int cols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

                    while (rs.next()) {

                        Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
                        InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();

                        String filepath = "";

                        filepath += FileOutDir + "/";

                        for (int c = 2; c <= cols; c++) {
                            filepath += rs.getObject(c).toString() + "_";
                        }

                        filepath = filepath.substring(0,
                                filepath.length() - 1);
                        filepath += fileSuffix;
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

                        int b = 0;
                        while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
                            fos.write(b);
                        }

                    }

                    selBlobs.close();
                    fos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gui, e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (conn == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gui,
                    "You have not selected a database.");
        } else {
            if (FileOutDir == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gui,
                        "You have not chosen a directory for your files.");
            } else {
                if (blobSQL == null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gui,
                            "Please insert an SQL statement.");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try using Buffered input and output streams?

Comment: isn't bufferedinput and bufferedoutput the same as input and output but with more functionality?

Comment: Buffered input and output makes reading and writing buffered operations, so they should be much faster for reading and writing - instead of reading and writing byte by byte, you could do it in chunks. Give it a try.

Comment: ok, I will. I'll be back with the results when I am done.

Comment: I figured it out it is about 100 times faster with the buffered reader.

Comment: That's good. You can post an answer to show how you achieved it for people who might have a similar question and will find this thread in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the help  Przemyslaw Kruglej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to a buffered output made the process exponentially faster. I was able to export the 727 files in under a minute. Here the new code:

```
//...

                    while (rs.next()) {

                        blob = rs.getBlob(1);
                        is = blob.getBinaryStream();
                        filepath += "/";

                        for (int c = 2; c <= cols; c++) {
                            filepath += rs.getObject(c).toString() + "_";
                        }
                        filepath = filepath.substring(0,
                                filepath.length() - 1);
                        filepath += fileSuffix;

                        fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filepath));

                        while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
                            fos.write(b);
                        }

                        filepath = FileOutDir;
                        b = 0;
                    }

 //...
```

Comment: There are other problems now, it seems that some of the files are missing some data. I asked another question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686232/extracting-blobs-to-files-some-files-are-missing-data